# Pick inside Compile

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

I want to compile this function:

```
fun = With[{a = Range[-300, -200]}, 
        Compile[{{t, _Integer}, {window, _Integer, 2}}, 
          Pick[a + t, #, 1] & /@ window, 
        CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
```

but

```
CompilePrint[fun]
```

returns `MainEvaluate` at `Pick`. Is there a workaround and is `Pick` not compilable in C?

**edit:** `window` is a sparse array and `fun` is actually a more complicated function that contains `Pick`.

Comment: Here's a discussion of compilable functions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Comment: Also `Pick` with packed arrays is already extremely fast, especially when the filtering function is optimized for packed arrrays, like `Unitize`, `UnitStep` etc. Compiling it would not give much boost.

Comment: I'm using Pick inside a more complicated function, but the only point it evaluates at the main kernel is Pick so that's how I phrased the question.

Comment: You cannot use sparse array in `Compile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `Pick` nor `SparseArrays` can be used in compiled function. But the following shows you how to achieve the desired operation more quickly *without* `Compile`, just by `SparseArray` techniques:

```
a = Range[-300, -200];
n = 100000;
m = 1000000;
i = RandomInteger[{1, n}, m];
j = RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}, m];
vals = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, m];
window = SparseArray[Transpose[{i, j}] -> vals, {n, Length[a]}];
t = RandomInteger[100];

result0 = Table[Pick[a + t, w, 1], {w, window}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

result = With[{A = SparseArray[ Clip[window, {0, 1}, {0, 0}].DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[a + t]]]},
     Internal`PartitionRagged[A["NonzeroValues"], Differences[A["RowPointers"]]]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result0 == result
```

> 0.63127
>
> 0.048193
>
> True